# Replace index values of one data frame with dates of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to change the index values of a given data frame (*fruits.df*) with dates of another data frame (*date.index*).

Example Data:

```
# fruits.df    
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:12
z <- 1:16
w <- 1:7
fruits.list <- list(Apples = x, Bananas = y, Grapes = z, Kiwis = w)

library(qpcR)
fruits.df <- do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, lapply(
   fruits.list, data.frame))

names(fruits.df) <- names(fruits.list)
```

This produces the following date frame:

[image]

Example data for the date index data frame:

```
date.index <- data.frame(Days = seq(as.Date("2017-07-01"), 
  as.Date("2017-07-20"), by = 1), index = as.integer(1:20))
```

So what I need is the following:

[image]

I have tried ti use the **filter** function of dplyr but it works only when I explicitly select a column.

Does not work:

```
filtered_found_Index <- filter(date.index, index %in% 
    fruits.df)
```

Works, but I need to do it at the same time with the whole df:

```
filtered_found_Index <- filter(date.index, index %in% 
    fruits.df$**Bananas**)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` on each column of your `fruits.df`, i.e.

```
fruits.df[] <- lapply(fruits.df, function(i) date.index$Days[match(i, date.index$index)])
```

which gives,

> ```
>        Apples    Bananas     Grapes      Kiwis
> 1  2017-07-01 2017-07-01 2017-07-01 2017-07-01
> 2  2017-07-02 2017-07-02 2017-07-02 2017-07-02
> 3  2017-07-03 2017-07-03 2017-07-03 2017-07-03
> 4  2017-07-04 2017-07-04 2017-07-04 2017-07-04
> 5  2017-07-05 2017-07-05 2017-07-05 2017-07-05
> 6        <NA> 2017-07-06 2017-07-06 2017-07-06
> 7        <NA> 2017-07-07 2017-07-07 2017-07-07
> 8        <NA> 2017-07-08 2017-07-08       <NA>
> 9        <NA> 2017-07-09 2017-07-09       <NA>
> 10       <NA> 2017-07-10 2017-07-10       <NA>
> 11       <NA> 2017-07-11 2017-07-11       <NA>
> 12       <NA> 2017-07-12 2017-07-12       <NA>
> 13       <NA>       <NA> 2017-07-13       <NA>
> 14       <NA>       <NA> 2017-07-14       <NA>
> 15       <NA>       <NA> 2017-07-15       <NA>
> 16       <NA>       <NA> 2017-07-16       <NA>
> ```